# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthGuard (?, JwtService, ConfigService). the argument UserModel at index [0] is available in the BookModule

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, jwt, nestjs

**auth.guard.ts**

```
import {
  CanActivate,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { User } from '../user/entities/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(User.name)
    private userModel: Model<User>,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
  ) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const token = this.extractTokenFromHeader(request);
    if (!token) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException(
        'You are not authorized to access this resource.',
      );
    }
    try {
      const payload = await this.jwtService.verifyAsync(token, {
        secret: this.configService.get<string>('JWT_SECRET'),
      });
      console.log('payload ->>', payload);
      const user = await this.userModel.findById(payload.id);

      if (!user) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException('User not found.');
      }
      request['user'] = user;
    } catch {
      throw new UnauthorizedException(
        'You are not authorized to access this resource.',
      );
    }
    return true;
  }

  private extractTokenFromHeader(request: Request): string | undefined {
    const [type, token] = request.headers.authorization?.split(' ') ?? [];
    return type === 'Bearer' ? token : undefined;
  }
}
```

**auth.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { JwtModule, JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UserSchema } from '../user/entities/user.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          global: true,
          secret: config.get<string>('JWT_SECRET'),
          signOptions: {
            expiresIn: config.get<string | number>('JWT_EXPIRES'),
          },
        };
      },
    }),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'User', schema: UserSchema }]),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtService],
  exports: [AuthService, JwtService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**book.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BookService } from './book.service';
import { BookController } from './book.controller';
import { BookSchema } from './schema/book.schema';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { AuthModule } from '../auth/auth.module';    
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Book', schema: BookSchema }]),
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [BookController],
  providers: [BookService],
})
export class BookModule {}
```

**book.controller.ts**

```
import {
  Body,
  Controller,
  Get,
  HttpStatus,
  Param,
  Post,
  Query,
  Req,
  Res,
  UseGuards,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { BookService } from './book.service';
import { CreateBookDto } from './dto/create-book.dto';
import { UpdateBookDto } from './dto/update-book.dto';
import { Book } from './schema/book.schema';
import { AuthGuard } from '../auth/auth.guard';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

@Controller({
  version: '1',
  path: 'books',
})
export class BookController {
  constructor(private bookService: BookService) {}

  @Post()
  async createBook(
    @Body()
    book: CreateBookDto,
  ): Promise<Book> {
    return this.bookService.create(book);
  }

  @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
  @Get()
  async getAllBooks(
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Res() res: Response,
    @Query() query: any,
  ): Promise<any> {
    console.log(req.user);

    const books = await this.bookService.findAll(query);
    return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
      data: books,
      statusCode: 200,
      message: 'Books fetched successfully.',
    });
  }
}
```

I am receiving

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthGuard (?, JwtService,
> ConfigService). Please make sure that the argument UserModel at index
> [0] is available in the BookModule context.

this error. i don't know what am i missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `UserModel` mongoose provider to be available in the context of `BookModule`. As you already have the provider created in the `AuthModule` via `MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'User', schema: UserSchema }])`, you can simply make use of [module re-exporting](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#module-re-exporting) and add `MongooseModule` to the `AuthModule`'s `exports` array.